# Javascript basico, no me funciona un listener

Tags: javascript

Como indico en el titulo, me encuentro en la primera practica de Javascript, en lo que el profesor explico en la primer clase, no me estaria funcionando, el codigo es el siguiente:

```js
const miBoton = document.getElementById("boton");


const ejecutar = evento => {
  alert("Chau");
}

miBoton.addEventListener("click", ejecutar);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="app.js"></script> //Link del JS
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="boton">Soy un Boton</button> //
  <--- Boton aca </body>

</html>
```

El error que me sale en la consola del navegador es el siguiente:

[image: error]

Muchas gracias

Comment: en qué navegador estás probando tu código?

Comment: Esto me parece raro, le di a probar codigo en stackoverflow ya que te deja probar tu codigo, y me funciona, pero directamente en mi direccion local no. Porque sera?

Comment: @RuslanLópez Brave

Comment: @RuslanLópez En opera tampoco funciona

Comment: @RuslanLópez Por ultimo, en Chrome tampoco

Comment: Acabo de copiar y probar tu código y funciona sin problemas

Comment: @BetaM Porque no me funciona?

Comment: Acabo de revisar y mi navegador predeterminado tiene activado Javascript

Comment: Puedes ir probando solo con function ejecutar() {
  alert("Chau");
} o con onclick, u otras variaciones de lo mismo, tal vez tu navegador no soporte algo.

Comment: @HatoriHanso Ejecuta el snippet, a nosotros nos corre. Si a tí no te corre te recomiendo poner las versiones específicas del navegador en la pregunta por si alguien supiera de algún problema en particular con ellas. Saludos

Comment: @RuslanLópez Que es el snippet

Comment: Eso de arriba con el botón de ejecutar en tu pregunta :3